# Flyway docker failing to find migration scripts - WARNING: Skipping filesystem location:./sql (not readable)

Tags: docker, flyway

I'm trying to run Flyway 6.5.7 via docker and it is failing to mount my scripts from the host to the ./sql path in the container.
I create a volume for the docker container and mount it as
`-v [localhost path]:/flyway/sql`,
my understanding is that the working directory in the Flyway container is `/flyway`.
I've set the location in the commandline as follows:
`-locations="filesystem:./sql"`

When I start the flyway container I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: Skipping filesystem location:./sql (not readable). Note this warning will become an error in Flyway 7.
```

The flyway_schema_history table gets created in my database, however, no scripts are found to be executed.

Is this some permissions thing with the Flyway docker container or am I missing something else?

Comment: `flyway/sql` is the default location where the https://github.com/flyway/flyway-docker expects the sql scripts, so what happens if you omit setting the -locations in command line?

Comment: If I remove -locations I still get the same message:
```Flyway Community Edition 6.5.7 by Redgate
WARNING: Skipping filesystem location:/flyway/sql (not readable). Note this warning will become an error in Flyway 7.```

Comment: have you tried setting `chmod o+r` for the folder mounted to `flyway/sql`?

Comment: That's it!!!  Nice!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @pero_hero for figuring it out!  I needed to set permissions on my local directory I am mounting.